# How is data centres allocating the correct resources?

Tags: cloud, resources

I've been using Microsoft Azure for a while and I'm a bit curious how the hardware resources in a data centre are allocated according to the selections that you make.

For example if I choose a hardware setup of "1 core, 1.75 GB RAM" on my instance, how is that restricted on the server? I mean there is a lot of apps on every server.

Or is every instance / app allocated as a new virtual machine?

Comment: I don't think the details of Azure's resource allocation system is a data science problem.

Comment: Ok. Which forum do you think is best for this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is just simple big virtualization cluster, nothing special behind it, same as in AWS, GoGrid, rackspace and another cloud providers.